# $set won't work for nested schema in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
module.exports.applyAd = function(id, applicant_id, callback){
    console.log(id)
    console.log(applicant_id)
    Ad.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id},
        {$set: {"applicant._id]": applicant_id}},
        {upsert: true, new: true})
        .exec(callback)
}
```

I have a mongoose function in my model, but the record in db remain unchanged, no error.

My schema look like this

```
const adSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    ...
    applicant: {
        _id: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            default: null
        }
    }
});
```

Any clue what's wrong?

Comment: Typo `"applicant._id]"` should be `"applicant._id"`

Comment: @NeilLunn ops, nice catch!